# Survey of actual hardware and software setups for websites, along with site usage information?

Tags: hardware, server-setup

I'm looking for blog posts / articles by various site owners that give exact specifications of their hardware, software and network setups, along with the site usage information.

I'm working on a research paper / survey that studies various software/hardware configurations and how they scale to handle increasing loads.

I've located one or two popular websites which share this information (eg: http://engineering.twitter.com/), but I'm looking for more extensive input on this.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.highscalability.com has links to pretty much every company that's ever released information like this.